# How can I cycle colors using turtle module in python?

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a rainbow straight line but can't figure out the way the RGB  values in `turtle.pencolor()` should change over time...

I tried using a hexadesimal increment from `000000` to `FFFFFF` but I got a a black to green line loop before getting an invalid color value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is Python turtle's RGB-based colors are the wrong model for easily generating a rainbow line.  Fortunately, you can `import colorsys` to work with a more appropriate model, like HSV, and have it convert those values to RGB:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb

RADIUS = 300
WIDTH = 100

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
turtle.width(WIDTH)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-RADIUS)
turtle.pendown()

for angle in range(360):
    turtle.pencolor(hsv_to_rgb(angle / 360, 0.75, 0.75))
    turtle.circle(RADIUS, 1)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Here we're just adjusting the *hue* based on the angle and leaving the *saturation* and *value* constant:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have even less patience, you can set the turtle module's "tracer" function to (0, 0)

eg. `t.tracer(0, 0)`

This will make the drawing appear instantly.

`t.tracer(20, 0)` will make the turtle go hyperspeed but still with some animation

you also need `t.update()` at the end if you use this method.